# Replace old password with new random password in multiple files using shellscript

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to replace the passwords present in multiple files with new random passwords.
I figured a way with sed to do this, but the problem is when I run this sed to a file, its replacing all the passwords with same value, which has to a different one for each value.

```
cat admin/secrets.ini | sed -e "s/"password:\ .*"/"password:\ `openssl rand -base64 18`"/g"
```

Grep before sed

```
sh-3.2# grep -i password adminsrv/secrets.ini
x_db_password: d3RBSmhykadfnvkadfWcHdDUA==
y_db_password: WXNKVFEunfvabfvlURzNFeQ==
z_password: Ymfvmidmlu
```

Grep after sed

```
sh-3.2# grep -i password adminsrv/secrets.ini
x_db_password: uTtDyP7aNeONxxOD7MhFH5Eb
y_db_password: uTtDyP7aNeONxxOD7MhFH5Eb
z_password: uTtDyP7aNeONxxOD7MhFH5Eb
```

Here I want every value to be replaced into a new random value in multiple such files.

Please suggest, if there is anyother way to do this in a single script.

Comment: If you have gnu sed, take a look at the `e` flag (gnu only) of the `s` command: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk` version that seems to work.

```
cat admin/secrets.ini
Not this
x_db_password: d3RBSmhykadfnvkadfWcHdDUA==
y_db_password: WXNKVFEunfvabfvlURzNFeQ==
z_password: Ymfvmidmlu
Not this

awk '/password/ {printf "%s ",$1;system("openssl rand -base64 18")} !/password/' admin/secrets.ini
Not this
x_db_password: d3RBSmhykadfnvkadfWcHdDUA==
y_db_password: WXNKVFEunfvabfvlURzNFeQ==
z_password: Ymfvmidmlu
Not this
```

Answer (score 0):

you mean something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
   echo "${line% *} $(openssl rand -base64 18)" 
done < secrets.ini > new_secrets.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally the working script. Thanks to @Jotne

```
N=$(date +%s)
rsync --recursive secrets/core/* secrets/$N/
for i in `find secrets/$N/* -iname secrets.ini`; 
do 
awk '/password/ {printf "%s ",$1;system("openssl rand -base64 18")} !/password/' $i > $i.tmp && mv $i.tmp $i; 
done
```